# Can you truncate std::vector<int> in constant time?

Tags: c++, stdvector

There are several ways to make a vector empty, including

```
std::vector<int> example = makeMyReallyBigVector();
example.clear();
example.resize(0);
example.erase(example::being(), example::end());
// any other method which would be relevant
```

Are there any guarantees in the C++ standard about which is most efficient, time-wise? The contents are a primitive data type without destructor. What I am especially concerned about is, I don't want the vector capacity to change, I just want it's internal "used size" set to 0 without touching the now-erased contents.

What I want is to set the `int` vector size to 0 in constant time, without freeing any memory. Is this possible with C++ standard?

If the C++ standard gives no guarantees, I'm using GNU C++ standard library, so if standard doesn't, does that give any guarantees? For sake of portability, in this case also information about the Clang and Microsoft standard libraries would of interest, of course.

Comment: All three of those methods will end up doing the same thing in your case, so use whichever one you want.

Comment: You want something faster than O(n)? All of them are O(n)

Comment: @LouisGo For _int_ vector, I'd expect/want it to be O(1), setting one private variable to 0.

Comment: You can always check the generated machine code. For example, in this live demo, it is practically the same in all three cases: https://godbolt.org/z/c6r4haofY.

Comment: @LouisGo In theory yes. In practice, if the destruction operation for the value type is effectively no-op, then it may be optimized to O(1) machine code.

Comment: @hyde -- Good point.  That's why I stress to never write an empty destructor, and just leave it out or declare it `=default`.   Writing an empty destructor changes the traits of the class, and the optimization you speak of may not happen if the traits of the type stored in the vector are not trivially-destructible.

Comment: @DanielLangr On a tangent, that's curious, why is there this test and jump here, instead of just straight write: `mov rax, QWORD PTR [rdi] ; cmp rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8] ; je .L1 ; mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], rax ; L1:` ? Is writing to memory really so exemsive, that's it's worth it to check if the write is needed?

Comment: @DanielLangr Also, interestingly, while *gcc* seems to produce the same code for all, *clang* seems to be unable to optimize `erase` as well. So it does matter at least sometimes, which of these three lines is used.

Comment: @Raildex resize does not reduce capacity.

Comment: @hyde I am not sure about the reason for the check. But the compiler might want to avoid writes, since it makes the cache line dirty. This may come with some overhead, especially in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 5):

```
example.clear();
```

[`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) is :

> Linear in the size of the container, i.e., the number of elements.

```
example.resize(0);
```

[`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) is

> Linear in the difference between the current size and count. Additional complexity possible due to reallocation if capacity is less than count

```
example.erase(example::begin(), example::end());
```

[`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) is

> Linear: the number of calls to the destructor of T is the same as the number of elements erased, the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements

I am not sure why neither `clear` nor `resize` mention the dependence on the destructor. `int` has only a pseudo-destructor (something that makes calling the destructor on an `int` valid, but it doesn't do anything).

If the elements do have a destructor the complexitiy is linear. For `int` the compiler may be clever enough to do it in constant time. When you are not sure about runtime you can profile the run, or directly read the disassembly code.

Answer (score 1):

`example.clear();` may be faster. All of the above examples take arguments, which means that additional code will be generated to pass them to the function, which will need to be executed.

However, it's important to remember that the C++ compiler is pretty smart and might be able to turn `example.resize(0);` into `example.clear();`. But it is not exactly. So it's better to help the compiler, if not difficult.

Comment: Just a note: I added one paragraph to the question to clarify what I want to achieve.

Comment: Most of the STL code is inlined anyway, so passing parameters does not generate more code (even if optimization is turned off). I would recommend use `clear()` just because it is more explicitly stating what you are doing.

Comment: @hyde , Usually, there are not as many guarantees in the STL as we would like. If you need a container that is guaranteed to work exactly the way you want, write your own. This is not difficult at all, in fact, not difficult when it comes to int, for example. I recommend doing this through `malloc` from `cstdlib`.

Comment: @JakobStark, It seems like there are no clear guarantees on this situation in each individual case. That is, yes, it happens, but to make sure - you need to compile certain code in certain version of the compiler for the certain platform...

Comment: @AlexA. If you ask me, it's almost never a good idea to write your own container, _unless it's as a learning exercise_. If the standard containers really don't cut it, there are other well-tested libraries to go to. And using `malloc`, or, indeed, a naked `new` in modern C++ code is something I would strongly advice against. just use `std::make_unique` in any place where you would use a naked `new` (or `malloc`).

Comment: @hyde, if you want a really guaranteed effective code, you must use C in C++ sometimes. `new` doesn't have an ability to resize, but `malloc` has: `realloc`. The C++ compiler can do very complex optimizations indeed, but not all of them. To know what exactly and in which case the compiler is guaranteed to improve, you need to know very well the list of optimizations in each compiler and their applicability in each case. To be sure, you need to look at the disassembled code at the output of the compiler.